# Run VMWare Interpreter in local IDE

Tags: python, virtual-machine, pycharm

I have ubuntu in my VMWare and local has Windows 7. I want to use Ubuntu Python Interpreter but write scripts in my Windows 7 pycharm. What are the solutions?

Comment: (Disclaimer - I haven't used Pycharm.) You may need to clarify what you're asking for. My first thought was that you can always write scripts on your Windows machine, copy them to the VM, then run in the VM. But if you meant setting your Windows Pycharm to run Ubuntu Python.. I doubt that's possible, they're totally different systems.

Comment: Also, there appears to be a 'pycharm' tag, you may want to consider adding that so those users will see this question :)

Comment: winscp or any other sftp client?

Comment: @ilaunchpad have you tried the pycharm remote interpreter settings ? Does that works for you ?

Comment: @JorgeVidinha I did. And it works. :)

Comment: @ilaunchpad great !!! Why not accept the answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

You wil need pycharm remote interpreter not available at the comunity version of pycharm  see > https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/configuring-remote-python-interpreters.html